# how to create custom saveactions at content tree side

Tags: content-editor, sitecore-forms

sitecore 9.1 how to create forms **saveactions** at content tree side,like sitecore 8.2 wffm's saveactions.?

In sitecore 9.1 directly select save action at forms module but we need to same at content tree side same as sitecore 8.2 wffm forms, please help me ..

thanks

Comment: You want to make something happen, when people save an item in the Content Editor?

Comment: Sounds like, for Sitecore Forms wants to create a custom save action?